# Python sqlite3: query executes correctly in one place but same syntax fails with tkintertable

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, sqlite

I'm working with sqlite3 and trying to get it to retrieve database records for each entry in a `tkintertable`.  Problem is, the query keeps failing, even though everything about it looks identical to a test problem that does work.

The following code works, giving me the desired entry from the SQLite database:

```
key_value = 309
query_parameters = tuple([key_value])
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM 'Ship' WHERE [Ship Key]=?""",query_parameters)
a = cursor.fetchall()
```

However, this search returns only an empty list, []:

```
this_ship_index = int(self.shipsTable.thisModel.getCellRecord(i, annex_key_index))
query_parameters = tuple([this_ship_index])
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM 'Ship' WHERE [Ship Key]=?""",query_parameters)
this_record = cursor.fetchall()
```

Here's the weird part: I did a step by step execution and verified that `this_ship_index` is an `int` variable with a value of 309, the same as `key_value` in the test code.  `query_parameters` for both of them is a tuple with the value `(309,)`.

And yet the same query, executed with parameters that seem identical, is returning two completely different results at different times.  What's going on here?

Comment: The rows no longer exist from the first run to the next?

Comment: Nope, I've done it several times and always gotten the same results.  The underlying database isn't being changed at all.